# setCoords of all objects in group in fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

Im currently developing a editor for customizing signs and ran into a problem with positioning text element after an increase of the font size. The text objects is currently in a group but its possible to set font-size of each individual object. When increasing font size I need to setCoords for the full group, otherwise the end-user is not able to move it properly.

Can I use setCoords on the Group Object or do I need to loop through all objects in the group and set coords on each individually, if this is the case, any suggestions how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have written an editor for seat reservation system with using of Fabric.js. One of the features is cloning selected objects. Selected objects are cloned, moved right and bottom and this new group of objects is marked as active group. After clonning and shifting I am using group.setCoords() and group.saveCoords() and everything works fine. Check my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43079404/2598453).